# Change sendmail_path using ini_set in PHP

Tags: php, sendmail, ini-set

Can i set `sendmail_path` using `ini_set` in php page, without changing in `php.ini` file ?
Like this :

```
 ini_set("SMTP","smtp.gmail.com");
 ini_set("smtp_port","587");
```

My application will run on a shared server, and we can't change server's configurations file.
This is my first question here , so apologizes for any mistakes.

Comment: hello and welcome to so :D you can modify it by ini_set() but keep in mind ... SMTP and smtp_port flag will only work for WINDOWS-SERVER ... and have no value for UNIX/LINUX Servers as you can read here http://php.net/manual/en/mail.configuration.php#ini.smtp-port

Answer (score 2):

According to [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/mail.configuration.php#ini.sendmail-path) you can only set this parameter from `php.ini` or `httpd.conf`. i.e. changable from = `PHP_INI_SYSTEM`

Comment: I successfully send mail using , PHPMailer without do changes in php.ini file or httpd.conf file. But now i have a different problem.       From address is being unchanged and always take the from address, which is used by me for gmail authentication. Now what should i do for chagne in from address ??

Comment: I am afraid you will have to ask that as a new question. Make sure you add your code so we can see what you are doing with phpMailer

Comment: More info on `PHP_INI_SYSTEM`: http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.modes.php